# Is it natural and correct to say "talk via audio" meaning to actually talk to someone over the phone rather than text?

Tags: phrase-choice, collocations

Is it natural and correct to say *talk via audio* meaning to actually talk to someone over the phone rather than text? For example:

> Do you prefer to talk **via** text or **audio**?

If it sounds off, would it be more natural to say *talk via phone call*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *audio* here is awkward.

---

Informally, assuming the right context, I would drop *talk* and *via* altogether, and replace *audio* with *phone*:

> Do you prefer text or phone?

It can also be phrased differently:

> Do you prefer texting or calling?

---

More formally, I would replace *talk* with *communicate*, and I'd probably replace *via* with *over*:

> Do you prefer communicating over text or phone?

Or there is the following variation:

> Do you prefer writing texts or making phone calls?

Comment: There are hundreds of ways of saying this,  e.g. *Do you prefer making phone calls or using WhatsApp?* OR  *Are you someone who uses the phone or text?* Never heard of  telephones being called "audio" before, it's not just awkward, it's totally the wrong expression.  It's like asking  "Do you prefer watching via vision or the internet?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd talk via audio over the internet but I'd only ever talk "on the phone". I'm British, I've heard Americans talk "over the phone" but not "via audio" when they mean phone.